# What is the equivalent of the "bank_account" type/object under the Charge API in the newer Payments API in Stripe?

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments

I'm working on migrating our codebase from using the Source API to the Payments API in Stripe. As a jumping off point I've been [following this migration guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/transitioning).  I'm at the point where I'm [migrating our code that reads from charges](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration/charges?read-migration=sources#read) and am trying to figure out what the new equivalent of the type "bank_account" may be.

An example of our current code is as follows:

```
const source = charge.source;  // charge is of type Stripe.Charge

if (source.object === 'card') {
   let month = source.exp_month;
   let lastFour = source.last4;
   ... 
} else if (source.object === 'bank_account') {
   let bank = source.metadata.bank;
   let fingerprint = source.fingerprint;
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

For the migration aspect I have this so far, with the question being how to handle our existing check for 'bank_account':

```
const paymentMethodDetails = charge.payment_method_details;  // charge is of type Stripe.Charge

if (paymentMethodDetails.type === 'card') {
   let month = paymentMethodDetails.card.exp_month;
   let lastFour = paymentMethodDetails.card.last4;
   ... 
} else if (paymentMethodDetails.type === ?????) { // <-- here's the question
   let bank = paymentMethodDetails.??????
   let fingerprint = paymentMethodDetails.??????
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

The list of types in the Stripe documentation doesn't include "bank_account" as an option, and while there is a payment_method.details.card object available, there isn't a payment_method_details.bank_account object available.

Any guidance is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the type you're looking for is `us_bank_account`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-payment_method_details-type

Then, you'd use `bank=paymentMethodDetails.us_bank_account.bank_name` and `fingerprint=paymentMethodDetails.us_bank_account.fingerprint`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-payment_method_details-us_bank_account

Comment: I see that as a possibility, but what about the "us_bank_account" option [shown here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-type)?

Comment: Ah, good find! `ach_debit` looks to be associated with an older flow. 
`us_bank_account` is the right type. You'll use `paymentMethodDetails.us_bank_account.bank_name` and `paymentMethodDetails.us_bank_account.fingerprint`.

Comment: Right.  If you edit your answer I'll still accept it!

Comment: Turns out that both `ach_debit` AND `us_bank_account` are commonly used depending on the scenario.  You may want to edit your answer to reflect that.  :)